# How to change format for the date in angular pikaday

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pikaday

I am using pikaday library for my angularjs app for datepicker but can't change the format for the date and my html element looks like this:

```
<input pikaday="clas.myPicker" class="form-control" on-select="clas.onPikadaySelect(pikaday)">
```

The format shows as: Aug 30 2016, I would want it 2016-08-30.

I see that I have to use moment.js, I tried this: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment but my angularjs version is 1.2.16 quite old and I cannot install it.

I also have this on the app config in angularjs:

```
 .config(['pikadayConfigProvider', function (pikaday) {
    pikaday.setConfig({
        // numberOfMonths: 1,
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
    });
}])
```

Is there any other option how do I change the format of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use angular-moment.

What you should do is to include momentjs script on your HTML page before you include pickaday.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Like in this [example](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/blob/master/examples/moment.html). Pickaday format option will work.

Comment: awesome, u saved me dude.